# How to inverse Core Graphics Context drawing in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm using the below code to draw and remove drawing in an UIView. Now, I need to find a way to inverse the drawing. By clicking a button I have to paint only the non-painted part of my view. Can I use the existing lines array to calculate the path using the touch event and invert it? Or How can I redraw to inverse the drawing with a single click?

[image: What I have achieved using this code.]

```
struct Line {
    var points: [CGPoint]
    var strokeColor: UIColor
    var strokeWidth: CGFloat
}
```

```
class CanvasView: UIView {
        
    var vm: viewModel = viewModel.instance ---> var lines: [Line] = []
    
    private var strokeWidth: CGFloat = 25.0
    private var strokeColor: UIColor = .white
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        vm.lines.forEach { line in
            context.setStrokeColor(line.strokeColor.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(line.strokeWidth)
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            context.setLineJoin(.round)
            
            for (index, point) in line.points.enumerated() {
                if index == 0 {
                    context.move(to: point)
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: point)
                }
            }
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }
    
    func clear() {
        vm.lines.removeAll()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    func inverse() {
        // Inverse the drawing
        
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        let newLine = Line(points: [point], strokeColor: strokeColor, strokeWidth: strokeWidth)
        
                vm.lines.append(newLine)
//                setNeedsDisplay()
    }
        
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        guard var lastLine = vm.lines.popLast() else { return }
                
                lastLine.points.append(point)
                vm.lines.append(lastLine)
                setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Now, I want to invert the drawing in my UIView. I can see people fill them using Even Odd (EO) fill-in for CAShapeLayers. Is it possible to do a similar method? Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: The output I'm expecting.]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inverse" here? You mention "painting the non-painted" parts. Do you mean you simply want to fill the unpainted parts with a single color? Or when you say "inverse" to you mean reverse the colors? Or something else? You should post a sample before and after image to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an after picture. I want to fill the unpainted parts with the same colour I used to paint the canvas view and remove what was already painted.

Comment: You are only drawing fat lines. It seems like all you need to do is to swap the background and stroke colors to get what you want for inverse.

Comment: I'm clearing the background colour of the uiview. So swapping backgrounds is not working for me. I have attached the sample images in the question.